# How do I ensure that the text of my UIButton is not shortened?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I changed the text of my UIButton to a long equation. Unfortunately, my text is shortened.

[image]

How do I prevent shortening? It shortens my text even when I specify "Clip" or "Word Wrap" in the Nib.

Comment: To make Word Wrap work just add spaces in your string.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want word wrap though. I just want the text to fill the button and not be shortened with ellipses.

Comment: Do you generate text for a button at runtime?

Comment: No, I have some default text in my nib file ("Function 1" and "Function 2").

Comment: Then you can try to change the font size to a bit smaller.

Comment: Thank you, though is there a way to force iOS to not clip text?

Comment: Not for a button I guess. You can use a little hack to make your text on a button look better - just put under a button with no text a UILabel with desired text (it has more options for text formatting than a UIButton) and set your button transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call these two methods and your button will automatically adjust to the size of the text:

`[myButton sizeToFit]; [mybutton setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: Thank you, but I believe the button is simply shortening now to the size of the text, whereas I want the text to fill the entire button.